# How to get notification on iOS on change of network in not running state

Tags: ios, swift

In Android there is a broadcast sent by the OS whenever there is change in system configurations(like change in network state etc).
Those broadcast messages can be received by the broadcastreceiver in our app and change the behaviour of the app accordingly,though our app is not in running state. 
How I can achieve the similar broadcastreceiver behavior in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to monitor changes.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "batteryLevelChanged:",
    name: NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification,
    object: nil)
```

Here is the API reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/

**EDIT 1:**

For your case, you can follow the steps and try.

1. Using library [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) to get notification on changing of
   network and define customized notification function.

---

```
func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {

  let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

  if reachability.isReachable() {
    if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
      print("Reachable via WiFi")
    } else {
      print("Reachable via Cellular")
    }
  } else {
    print("Network not reachable")
  }
}
```

2. In your notification function, create a corresponding local
   notification

---

```
var notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = "Notification message!!!" // text that will be displayed in the notification
notification.alertAction = "open" // text that is displayed after "slide to..." on the lock screen - defaults to "slide to view"
notification.fireDate = NSDate() // todo item due date (when notification will be fired)
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound
notification.userInfo = ["UUID": UUID, ] // assign a unique identifier to the notification so that we can retrieve it later
notification.category = "CATEGORY"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: thanks for reply. May be my question is not clear. My expectation is to get local notification either alert, or notification on status bar or even badge on network state change(e.g, if we change from WiFi to data card or vise versa). And that should get triggered even if my application is not in running state.

Comment: Understand, then there already have a library for your request https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift.

Comment: Thanks @BobGao,I studied Reachability and it does as expected. Can it work if my application is not in running state, and i should get notification on notification bar if i change my network state.

Comment: Hi @user3513902, I've updated my answer, please try, there is an important point is that you must start the app first and turn it into background for testing, otherwise, the notification wouldn't be cached.

Comment: Thanks BobGao, really helped a lot. So our app should be running in background in order to receive notification? In android app with broadcastreceiver we are able to get notification without even running in background (Note: it is obvious to run first time to register for notification).

Comment: Apple add background execution for some background jobs, but I'm not sure whether you can get the notification of changing of system status and tigger your own local notification in background execution, maybe you can try it, here is the link for your reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 0):

You have use **Reachability** class in order to implement network change notification, here is example:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_h.html